# How to refer conditional resources on another resource in terraform

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I created 2 buckets. One will create always and one will create when env is QA.

```
resource "aws_s3_bucket" "bucket_always" {
  bucket_prefix = format("bucket.always")
  acl           = "private"

  versioning {
    enabled = true
  }

  server_side_encryption_configuration {
    rule {
      apply_server_side_encryption_by_default {
        sse_algorithm = "aws:kms"
      }
    }
  }
} 

resource "aws_s3_bucket" "bucket_conditional" {
  count = var.name == "qa" ? 1 : 0
  bucket_prefix = format("bucket.conditional")
  acl           = "private"

  versioning {
    enabled = true
  }

  server_side_encryption_configuration {
    rule {
      apply_server_side_encryption_by_default {
        sse_algorithm = "aws:kms"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Now how can I create an IAM and add both buckets arn? The below policy won't work because of conditional bucket

```
data "aws_iam_policy_document" "test_policy_document" {
  statement {
    actions = [
      "s3:ListBucket",
    ]

    resources = [
      aws_s3_bucket.bucket_always.arn,
      aws_s3_bucket.bucket_conditional.arn,
    ]
  }

  statement {
    actions = [
      "s3:PutObject",
      "s3:GetObject",
      "s3:DeleteObject",
    ]

    resources = [
      "${aws_s3_bucket.bucket_always.arn}/*",
      "${aws_s3_bucket.bucket_conditional.arn}/*",
    ]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Split the IAM statements up, and use [dynamic blocks](https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/expressions/dynamic-blocks.html). You don't really need to iterate over a specific list of values here, just pass it a list with one value if you want to create the block, or an empty list if you don't want to create the block. For example:

```
data "aws_iam_policy_document" "test_policy_document" {
  statement {
    actions = [
      "s3:ListBucket",
    ]

    resources = [
      aws_s3_bucket.bucket_always.arn
    ]
  }

  statement {
    actions = [
      "s3:PutObject",
      "s3:GetObject",
      "s3:DeleteObject",
    ]

    resources = [
      "${aws_s3_bucket.bucket_always.arn}/*"
    ]
  }

  dynamic "statement" {
    for_each = var.name == "qa" ? ["qa"] : []
    content {
      actions = [
        "s3:ListBucket",
      ]

      resources = [
        aws_s3_bucket.bucket_conditional[0].arn
      ]
    }
  }

  dynamic "statement" {
    for_each = var.name == "qa" ? ["qa"] : []
    content {
      actions = [
        "s3:PutObject",
        "s3:GetObject",
        "s3:DeleteObject",
      ]

      resources = [
        "${aws_s3_bucket.bucket_conditional[0].arn}/*"
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks this resolved my issue. The only change needed in your answer is
aws_s3_bucket.bucket_conditional[0].arn and "${aws_s3_bucket.bucket_conditional[0].arn}/*"